# Symfony 3.4 and Doctrine events (prePersist, etc.) - is it possible to grab a route variable and use it in the event listener?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, event-listener

I have a couple Doctrine event listeners that fire upon form submission.  I want to redirect to certain routes if an exception occurs, but these destination routes have database IDs that I cannot predict.  They *are*, however, present in the routes that generate these forms.  Is there a way for me to pass the IDs that are in the origin route to the event listener?  I don't have direct access to the events since they're a part of Doctrine.

Comment: Just inject the [request stack](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-request-stack) into your listener and then pull the master request out of it when you need it.

Comment: Is it possible to inject the `Request` object instead?  According to your link, it was planned for 3.0

Comment: Nope.  Requests can be nested so there is no single request object.  Plus there can be life cycle issues.  Just inject the request stack then when you actually need it, $this->requestStack->getMasterRequest() will do the trick.

Comment: I don't have the chance to change my code until later tonight, but I need to ask: will the stack have the name of the route that was hit, as well as the parameters passed in?  I mean, I could parse the actual request if necessary, but would rather have it done for me by the system

Comment: The stack simply holds the request objects.  Once you get the request object then you have access to all the usual attributes.  Including the _route attribute which has the name of the matched route.  You might be overthinking what the request stack object is.  Nothing mysterious.

Comment: Okay, thanks!  If you feel like it, you can write your comment as an answer and I'll upvote